# Configure Maven not to run tests if nothing changed

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

We have a large application consisting of many modules and full build (with integration tests) takes up to hour.
Is there a way to configure maven in the way that it will skip tests on modules (or even classes), where nothing has been changed?
Probably some plugin exists for that or this plugin can be written?

Comment: I havent tryied myself but the best approach seems to be maven incremental build plugin described here: http://harshana05.blogspot.ch/search?q=incremental+maven

Comment: Id love to hear about your success with this (since we have multi module projects maintained on GIT were all of the different branches are build on the same Jenkins instance hence resulting in build scenarios that can take up to 24 hours i consider having a closer look at this too).

Comment: I did this with a combination of sed/awk and `git diff --name-only`  to get the modules that have changed since a revision then do a mvn -amd -pl modulenames clean install

Comment: Maven is just not really suited for this. Build tools like Bazel are. You can build and run tests only on affected parts and you're able to determine the granularity yourself.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for can be achieved by using [gitflow-incremental-builder](https://github.com/gitflow-incremental-builder/gitflow-incremental-builder) plugin, although it has dependency on git.

> A maven extension for incremental building of multi-module
> projects when using feature branches (Git Flow).
> Builds or tests only changed maven modules compared to
> reference branch in Git (e.g. origin/develop) and all their dependents.

Powered by JGit.

Answer (score 0):

You could bite the bullet on this one and take your expensive (by cpu cycles) integration tests out of the main build.

The you can run your project with -Pintegrationtests via a separate scheduling mechanism.

For example, you could run them 4 times daily, on a cron schedule.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "release-manager" you could run the test using the pre-commit-check using the variable `$pending_change_modules`.

In example: If you commit to modul `foobar` then this command is executed:

```
mvn test -pl foobar
```

**Warning: If the test fail the commit is rejected.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maven doesn't inherently support skipping tests based on whether a module's source code has changed. However, you can approximate such functionality using a combination of Maven profiles and carefully crafted commands.

First, if you aren't using them already, modularize your code using Maven Modules. Each module should have its own pom.xml. Then, you can use Maven profiles to skip tests for each module:

```
<profile>
    <id>skipTests</id>
    <properties>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

You can activate this profile when building a module to skip tests:

```
mvn clean install -PskipTests
```

- Checks which files have changed since the last commit.
- Determines which module(s) those files belong to.
- Builds only those modules without skipping tests.
- Builds the rest of the modules with the skipTests profile active.